# Excuding assemblies when building with AOT

Tags: uno-platform

I need to add Uno.Core and System.Core assemblies to the excluded assemblies list before I am able to successfully run my application in InterpreterAndAOT mode. What impact does that have on performance? Why would these assemblies need to be excluded from the AOT build process?

I am getting the following error when not excluding Uno.Core and System.Core:

```
Uno.UI.js:111 Uncaught RuntimeError: memory access out of bounds
    at <anonymous>:wasm-function[55825]:0x13bc653
    at <anonymous>:wasm-function[104503]:0x25e36ce
    at <anonymous>:wasm-function[124001]:0x2e2c077
    at <anonymous>:wasm-function[42762]:0xd6a039
    at <anonymous>:wasm-function[60154]:0x15b59de
    at dynCall_iii (<anonymous>:wasm-function[151630]:0x342a152)
    at invoke_iii (http://localhost/dotnet.js:12348:12)
    at <anonymous>:wasm-function[18564]:0x60ef1e
    at dynCall_iiii (<anonymous>:wasm-function[151631]:0x342a160)
    at invoke_iiii (http://localhost/dotnet.js:12337:12)
```

Comment: Could you update your question with details about the errors you're getting when not excluding Uno.Core and System.Core ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a mono issue that has probably been fixed recently.

You may want to try using a recent experimental build of the `Uno.Wasm.Bootstrap` package and try again.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have been trying to test with the latest Uno.Wasm.Bootstrap package but I am unable to complete the test because updating to the latest Uno packages causes a build error. (As described in https://github.com/unoplatform/uno/issues/3315)

Comment: I have now been able to update to the latest Uno.Wasm.Bootstrap package but am getting the same behaviour when including System.Core and Uno.Core to the build. The error is the same as the one in the original question. Does that mean that this has not been fixed in mono yet?

Comment: Which version did you try ?